# Barplot sum of observations in two groups in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have data of the form:

```
mydata <- data.frame(test = 1:20, group = sample(c("A", "B"), 20, rep=TRUE), var1 = sample(c("yes", "no", "NA"), 20, rep=TRUE), var2 = sample(c("yes", "no", "NA"), 20, rep=TRUE), var3 = sample(c("yes", "no", "NA"), 20, rep=TRUE), var4 = sample(c("yes", "no", "NA"), 20, rep=TRUE), var5 = sample(c("yes", "no", "NA"), 20, rep=TRUE))
```

I would like to make a bar plot in which groups A and B are compared for the number of observations (frequency count) that have 0 "yes" entries, 1 "yes" entry, 2 "yes" entries all the way up to all 5 vars being "yes". The final result would be a bar plot with X-axis showing all the possible number of "yes" entries (0,1,2,3,4,5), the Y-axis showing count frequency and separate bars for groups A and B for each X value. The frequency count (bar height) for each group is the number of rows that have the given number of "yes" entries. Missing data (NA) is counted as "No". Looked at other posts, still not quite sure how to write this, thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
f1 <- function(x) sum(x=='yes')

mydata %>% 
      group_by(group) %>% 
      summarise_each(funs(f1), var1:var5) %>% 
      gather(Var, Val, var1:var5)%>%
      ggplot(., aes(x=Var, y=Val, fill=group))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position='dodge')
```

#### Update

Based on the comments on @Math's post, perhaps this helps

```
 df1 <-  gather(mydata, Var, Val, var1:var5) %>%
                   group_by(group, test) %>%
                   summarise(Val=sum(Val=='yes')) %>% 
                   group_by(group, Val) %>% 
                   summarise(n=n())

 left_join(expand.grid(group=unique(df1$group),
        Val= unique(df1$Val)), df1) %>% 
            mutate(n=replace(n, is.na(n), 0))%>%
            ggplot(., aes(x=Val, y=n, fill=group))+
             geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: strange, installed all packages but get get the following:  "error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @marcel Have you called `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Looks like I have a problem with dplyr:  Warning message: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.1.2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ I am working with R 3.1.0. Any way to do this with base functions?

Comment: @marcel You could upgrade to R 3.1.2

Comment: Got it working and this gives the correct solution, thank you. Any way to format the plot so that frequencies of 0 in one group don't result in a double-wide bar for the second group? thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The `barplot` functions accepts a matrix as argument and will group the bars according to the columns.

You can generate the matrix you want with `apply` on the columns (second argument==2) and then plot with `barplot`:

```
res=apply(as.matrix(mydata[,3:ncol(mydata)]), 2, function(cc) { return(c(sum(mydata$group=="A" & cc=="yes"), sum(mydata$group=="B" & cc=="yes"))) })
barplot(res, beside=T)
```

**EDIT**
To apply by row, the idea is the same, you want to generate a matrix for barplot.

```
mydata$count = apply(as.matrix(mydata[3:ncol(mydata)]), 1, 
function(cc) { return(sum(cc=="yes")) })
barmat = c()
for (ii in 1:range(mydata$count)[2]) {
    barmat = cbind(barmat, c(sum(mydata$group=="A" & mydata$count==ii),sum(mydata$group=="B" & mydata$count==ii) ))
}
colnames(barmat) = 1:range(mydata$count)[2]
barplot(barmat, beside=T)
```

Comment: I see, I did not explain well enough. Actually I hope to look row by row and ask how many "yes" entries in each row. Then plot the following; for group A, three observations (rows) had 0 "yes" entries, two rows had 1 "yes", etc.. and in group B, 2 rows had 0 "yes" entries, three rows had only 1 "yes", etc.., all the way up to the maximum of all 5 var being a "yes" . The x-axis labels would be "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"

Comment: Thank you this solution also works exactly right, using base functions.